# Почему при переопределении hashCode чаще всего используют просто число 31?

Tags: java, hashcode

Почему при переопределении hashCode чаще всего используют просто число 31?
Где-то слышал, что это число, было выбрано, с математической точки зрения, так как оно обеспечивает равномерное распределение hashCode функции, что обеспечивает минимальную вероятность появления коллизий.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

В [Effective Java](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321356683) Джошуа Блоха говорится, что:

> 31 было выбрано так как это нечётное простое число.

Если вопрос в том, почему именно 31, то это потому что операция умножения может быть заменена сдвигом и вычитанием для повышения производительности: `31 * i == (i << 5) - i`. Современные виртуальные машины делают такого рода оптимизации автоматически.

Можно так же почитать [это](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4045622):

> Из оставшихся четырех я, наверное, выберу P(31), так как его дешевле
>   вычислять на RISC архитектурах (потому что 31 разность двух степеней
>   двойки). Р(33) так же дешева для вычисления, но его производительность
>   незначительно хуже, и 33 - составное, что заставляет меня нервничать.

Comment: При использовании четного хеш код деградирует при переполнении переменной результата

Comment: @Invision я лишь привожу цитаты именитых людей в этой области, сам я в этом вопросе не такой специалист, к сожалению.

Comment: По теме: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/404477/#comment405107_404695

Comment: не ради того, чтобы задеть. Но простое число не может быть чётным, иначе делителей будет больше двух :-)

Comment: @YuraShinkarev `2`.

Comment: да, забыл про 2 :-)